# Moving Image interesting?

Tags: technique, prints, camera-design, technology-generations

Do you think we will be able to print moving images soon? Would people buy and use such a camera? I’m working on a new design and technology for a camera. Would be glad to hear your opinions.

Comment: What's wrong with current cameras and (AM)OLED displays?

Comment: What you are talking about is called video. You can view such files on any TV, monitor, or smartphone. [Consumer (AM)OLED displays might soon be flexible, foldable, and extremely thin](https://www.cnet.com/news/lg-display-crazy-65-inch-oled-tv-can-roll-up-like-a-poster-ces-2018/) - but you would still consider them a screen, not paper.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Photo.SE. Unfortunately, as currently written, this question is not a good fit for Stack Exchange, and will probably be closed soon. Specifically, this question is an more of an invitation for open-ended discussion, rather than seeking to solve a specific, answerable, problem. Please refer to the help center's [What types of questions should I avoid asking](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Can you edit this question to make it less opinion-based?

Comment: Print moving images? What are you talking about? Please explain it in a straightforward way. And what photographic problem are you trying to solve? If you just want to chat, that's not what this site is meant for.

Comment: I'm not terribly certain that the print version of a .gif will ever hold a ton of value.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you think we will be able to print moving images soon?

Yes, it's an old idea. See [lenticular printing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenticular_printing).

The Red Bull channel has a video showing how easy it is to take the photographs and produce an excellent result in their YouTube video "[How to make lenticular images - Red Bull Illume](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8qD28TaFylc)" - viewing that provides numerous references to other videos offering the same advice.

Other links:

[Creating lenticular images with motion effect](https://triaxes.com/articles/lenticular_motion/)

[OptiGraphics Lenticular Printing](http://optigraphics.com/lenticular-printing/)

[ExplainThatStuff - Lenticular printing](http://www.explainthatstuff.com/lenticularprinting.html)

> Would people buy and use such a camera? I’m working on a new design and technology for a camera. Would be glad to hear your opinions.

I'm not sure we need a new camera, it's not terribly popular (like 3D) but if you greatly improve on what's available then you might singlehandedly bring it to the forefront.

[image: Dance Baby]

Answer (score 0):

That's definitely interesting. Those "mobing prints" exist already: is screens.
 Screen technologies are improved recurrently, especially to improve dynamic range, pixel density, size, thruthfullness in terms of color, viewable angle, eventually mechnical flexibility, and durability (eg., qled over oled).

People I guess enjoy improved quality and truthfullness. And all those aspect mentionned might contribute to this truthfullness.

There are meta medias, between movie (motion picture) and stills (pictures), but not everybody enjoy what is being done today (gif-like).